# Can't assign to function call

Tags: python

У меня есть список all_users, в который я помещаю словари 
person{'user_id': user_id, 'state': state}. Почему в дальнейшем я не могу переприсвоить значение по ключу 'state'? Я неправильно беру значение по ключу?

```
          for g in all_users:
                if g.get('user_id') == event.user_id:
                    g.get('state') = state_list[2]
```

Почему строка g.get('state') подсвечивается красным и почему это функцию нельзя вызвать(Can't assign to function call)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get()` - это метод для получения значения из словаря.

> почему это функцию нельзя вызвать(Can't assign to function call)?

Функцию вызвать можно. Проблема в том, что вы вызову функции пытаетесь присвоить значение, так делать уже нельзя.

Для присвоения значения:

```
g['state'] = state_list[2]
```